# No loader is configured for ".hbs" files in Vite project whit hbs files on node_modules

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, node-modules, vite, rollup

I have a project that has a dependency that is not bundled in node_modules. Inside that dependency there are some handlebar files that are used by the dependency. The problem is that my bundle fails if I add that dependency to the project. All I receive is `No loader is configured for ".hbs" files`.

I have tried [vite-plugin-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-handlebars), [rollup-plugin-handlebars-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-handlebars-plus) and [rollup-plugin-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-handlebars) without success. I have also tried to create my own rollup filter like this:

```
function hbsfilter( ) {

    return {
        name: 'hbsfilter',

        transform( code, id ) {
            if ( id.endsWith( '.hbs?raw' ) || id.endsWith( '.hbs' ) ) {
                return {
                    code: `export default ${JSON.stringify( code )};`,
                    map: { mappings: '' }
                };
            }

            return {
                code: code,
                map: { mappings: '' }
            };
        }
    };
}

exports.hbsfilter = hbsfilter;
```

even using multiple hooks like load, resolveId ... but looks like node_module files are not passed to these hooks. So how can I add a loader for `.hbs` files to vite or rollup so my bundle works?

Comment: Did you find an answer?